# iOS ad hoc distribution with .p12 from customer

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have an app developed and working with our company's profile and distribution cert.  I just recieved the .p12 from the company that we are going to be distributing to, and am trying to rebuild the app with their certificate.  However, when I select 'Archive' I receive

"No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychains signing certificates"

I believe I'm missing something here, but google and I can't figure it out.  Do I need a new profile with that certificate in it?  If so how do I go about uploading the .p12?

Thankyou very much.

Comment: is that p12 is export of certificate of private key of the file cross check that

Comment: how many computer do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the p12 you are enabling your computer to make releases for the outside company but what you need right now is the provisioning profile associated with that app (it will be specific if you have in app purchases or push notification otherwise it will be the default developer profile) and that .p12

[image]

Comment: so, from the customer company, do I need more than just the .p12 from them?  Do I need their provisioning profile as well?

Comment: Just remember once you have it you need to change the code sign in identity of the profile you are doing the archive (Debug,Ad-hoc,release) to the one of the customer. Then you can archive correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Check out your keychain, distribution  certificate has key. If not then install right certificate.

[image]

Comment: It does have a private key exactly like in your image.